# cyclops-react and async-retry: How to retry on timeout?

Tags: java, reactive-streams, cyclops-react

I'm starting to use cyclops-react with async-retry. I'm still a little bit lost with it.

I'm using SimpleReact and simulating a timeout from the server but I never receive a timeout with something like this:

```
private List<Object> executeParallel() {
    List<Object> result = new SimpleReact(mainThreadPool)
            .of(getSupplier())
            .withRetrier(new AsyncRetryExecutor(retryThreadPool)
                    .abortIf((t) -> !TimeoutException.class.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass()))
            )
            .retry(retrySupplier())
            .block()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}

private Supplier getSupplier() {
    return () -> someOperationThatTimesOut();
}

private Function<Supplier, Object> retrySupplier() {
    return supplier -> supplier.get();
}
```

What is missing there?

Comment: Hey Jorge, I'll add a detailed answer to this, but the function that can timeout should be supplied to the retry operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version works

```
 AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

@Test
public void executeParallel() {
    List<Object> result = new SimpleReact(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
            .of(getSupplier())
            .withRetrier(new AsyncRetryExecutor(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1))
            .retry(Supplier::get)
            .block()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
}

private Supplier<String> getSupplier() {
    return () -> {
        System.out.println("Attempt " + count.incrementAndGet());
        if(count.get()<4)
            throw ExceptionSoftener.throwSoftenedException(new TimeoutException());
        return "success";
    };
}
```

It will print out

```
Attempt 1
Attempt 2
Attempt 3
Attempt 4
[success]
```

I suspect you don't need the abortIf on the async-retrier, and I'm not sure what is going inside someOperationThatTimesOut() - that may be the key here.

Comment: Thanks for the response @john-mcClean. Basically yes. Everything was correct, but the operation that should timeout was not timing out due to a missconfiguration

Comment: Cool - if you have any more questions please do fire away! Thanks!